# What causes Completed PayPal payments to be logged in the "Accounts Receivable" account?

Tags: civicontribute, financial-accounts

When I run the "Event Participant Report" and try to show "Total Paid", I'm getting $0 for "Total Paid" (or just the PayPal fee amount, but that's a separate bug).

The cause is that when people pay by PayPal, the `to_financial_account_id` in `civicrm_entity_financial_trxn` is set to "Accounts Receivable".  I'm not sure why this would happen for a payment that is completed immediately.  Is this a misconfiguration on my part or a bug?